# Form can't insert items in MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, forms, cgi

I'm researching in several forums but can't find the issue in a simple form to insert information in a MySQL database. Can you find the error?

Thanks

Here's the HTML form code (hello.html):

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form method="get" action="hello2.py">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        Email: <input type="text" name="email">
        Plate: <input type="text" name="plate">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Python code (hello2.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
import cgi, cgitb

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

name = form.getvalue('name')
email = form.getvalue('email')
plate = form.getvalue('plate')

# Avoid script injection escaping the user input
name = cgi.escape(name)
email = cgi.escape(email)
plate = cgi.escape(plate)

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="mysql.example.com", port=3306, user="l", passwd="l", db="l")
cursor = db.cursor()

add_driver = ("INSERT INTO Users "
           "(UsersName, UsersEmail, UsersPlate) "
           "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")

cursor.execute(add_driver, (name, email, plate))
db.commit()
cursor.close()
db.close()

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print 
print """\
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Hello!</h2>
    <ul>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Comment: I can't debug this, sorry. There's no error, it's just not adding rows in MySQL.

Comment: If you run this using python app.py there must be an output with something, in case there's not any error there're several other possibilities and it's hard to guess

Answer (score -1):

sorround your code with try except to see the error if any

```
try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="mysql.example.com", port=3306, user="l", passwd="l", db="l")
    cursor = db.cursor()

    add_driver = ("INSERT INTO Users (UsersName, UsersEmail, UsersPlate) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")

    cursor.execute(add_driver, (name, email, plate))
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
except Exception e:
     print repr(e)
```

Comment: A solution is not a recommendation to add try/catch code, please send this kind of advices in a comment.